# Can't send email in PHP Contact Form on localhost, getting STARTTLS error?

Tags: php, email, server, localhost

Hey I'm very new to php but I've tried to make an email contact form from a video tutorial, and I get an error saying

> "Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. u84sm2258144ioi.53 - gsmtp in C:\xampp\htdocs\ContactForm\form_process.php on line 83".

*Must issue a STARTTLS command first*, I don't know what this is nor how to do it. I contacted my ISP and got the SMTP address (mail.mymts.net) and the port # (587), and I've put an email for the sendmail_from, (anexample@gmail.com) but I don't get why this sendemail_from is needed either because won't it be sent from whatever email is in the email textbox? Does this need to be the same as the $to address? Is this STARTTLS command only needed for the localhost, or would i need a version of it for when i actually host the site from somewhere? Sorry I have so many questions I just am very stuck and don't know what to do, and I'd appreciate if someone sold me what to write to fix this please. I've included my 2 php files. This is the LAST thing i need to fix before I can make my site live, and I can't do that until i test it locally.

Index.PHP (the form):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<?php include ('form_process.php');?>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/email.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>    
        <div id="navbar" class="li flex-container nav hidden-xs">
            <a class="nav-link flex-item " href="index.html#bottom">PHOTOGRAPHER</a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="Portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
            <a class="hplogo-a flex-item hidden-xs hidden-sm" href=""><img id="logo" src="Images/WHITELOGO.png" alt=""></a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="Investment.html">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">BLOG</a>
        </div>
        <div id="myNav" class="overlay hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a href="index.html#bottom">PHOTOGRAPHER</a>
                <a href="Portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                <a href="javascript:window.location.reload();">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a>
                <a href="#">BLOG</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span id="toggle" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()" class="hidden-sm hidden-lg hidden-md popup">&#9776; </span>
            <div class="container top email">

            <p class="eramble eramble1 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10 "> Finding a photographer is a delicate process and you really need to trust your instinct. You put your trust and faith in us to capture your most valuable memories and to tell your story through our camera.  You're here because you feel that my work can represent and accentuate the love between you and your fiancé.</p>
            <p class="eramble eramble2  col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">If this is the case, I would love to hear more about you and about your wedding day.  So, lets start here! </p>
            **<div class="email_form">  
                <form id="contact" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group row">

                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="fname">Name*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Your first name" type="text" tabindex="1" size="30" name="fname" value="<?= $fname ?>" autofocus>
                            <label for="fname" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">First Name</label> 
                            <span class="error"><?= $fname_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                            <label class="visuallyhidden" for="lname">lNAME</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Your last name" type="text" name="lname" value="<?= $lname ?>" tabindex="4" >
                            <label for="lname" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">Last Name</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $lname_error?> </span> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="email">Email Address*</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="2" >
                            <span class="error"><?= $email_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="phone1">Phone*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" size="4" maxlength="3" id="phone1" placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="text" name="phone1" value="<?= $phone1 ?>" tabindex="3" >
                            <label for="phone1" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">(###)</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $phone1_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <label class="visuallyhidden" for="phone2">Phone*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" size="4" maxlength="3" id="phone2" placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="text" name="phone2" value="<?= $phone2 ?>" tabindex="3" >
                            <label for="phone2" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">###</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $phone2_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <label class="visuallyhidden" for="phone3">Phone*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" size="5" maxlength="4" id="phone3" placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="text" name="phone3" value="<?= $phone3 ?>" tabindex="3" >
                            <label for="phone3" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">####</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $phone3_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="message">Message*</label>
                            <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." class="message1 form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message" tabindex="5" ><?php if(isset($_POST['message'])){ 
                    echo htmlentities ($_POST['message']); }?></textarea>
                            <span class="error"><?= $message_error?></span> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <button class="btn-default btn rbutton col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1" name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="success"><?= $success;?></div>
                </form>


            </div>
        </div>**
        <div class="container bottom faq">
            <h1>FAQ</h1>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>

            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer Lastanswer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>





        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <footer class="foot">
                <h6> AVAILABLE WORLDWIDE</h6>      <h6> 2049671111</h6>
                <a href="#">MRPOOPYBUTTHOLE@GMAIL.COM</a>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <script>

            function openNav() {
                document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
            }

            function closeNav() {
                document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
            }
        </script>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

form_process.php:

```
<?php 
// define variables and set to empty values
$fname_error = $lname_error = $email_error = $phone1_error = $phone2_error = $phone3_error = $message_error="";
$fname = $lname = $email = $phone1 = $phone2 = $phone3 = $message = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $fname_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $fname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
    $lname_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $lname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone1"])) {
    $phone1_error = "required";
  } else {
    $phone1 = test_input($_POST["phone1"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed

  }
  if (empty($_POST["phone2"])) {
    $phone2_error = "required";
  } else {
    $phone2 = test_input($_POST["phone2"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed

  }
  if (empty($_POST["phone3"])) {
    $phone3_error = "required";
  } else {
    $phone3 = test_input($_POST["phone3"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
  }    
  if (empty($_POST["url"])) {
    $url_error = "";
  } else {
    $url = test_input($_POST["url"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$url)) {
      $url_error = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message_error = "Message is required";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($fname_error == '' and $lname_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone1_error == '' and $phone2_error == '' and $phone3_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $to = 'thetalhasuboor@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $fname = $lname = $email = $phone1 = $phone2 = $phone3 = $message = $url = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be asking new questions before you have marked your earlier answered as accepted imho.

Comment: Okay sure but my issue hasnt been solved, when it is I will mark one as correcr

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply some configuration in your `php.ini`

```
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
```

Restart your `apache` server.

As shown in image, click on `config` and select `php.ini` to open the file. Paste the code in the file. Then click on stop button, after server stops, start again.

[image]

Comment: Where would i type this code? Also how do I restart my apache server?

Comment: Sorry could you also explain why those specific values are requires in ini_set? why is there smtp.gmail.com and why is the port 465?

Comment: okay I did that but now it says " mail(): SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 relaying denied"

Comment: Also why are we setting the smtp to a gmail address? and why that port when in my php.ini i set it to my ISP's one